# How to get all the Bulk Data Load Jobs submitted by a particular user?

Tags: bulk-api

Want to find out if an integration user has submitted any bulk data load jobs in the org. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/get_all_jobs.htm doesn't provide any parameter to filter by fields. Even we can't report on them

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the bulk data load jobs submitted by a particular user by using the [Bulk Data Load Jobs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.monitoring_async_api_jobs_details.htm&language=en_us&type=5) page in Setup or by using [Bulk API 2.0 or Bulk API 1.0 to query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_walkthrough.htm) the job details.

- From Setup, enter **Bulk Data Load Jobs** in the Quick Find box, then select **Bulk Data Load Jobs**.
- You will see a list of all the bulk data load jobs in your org, with
  information such as the job ID, status, operation, object, submitted
  by, and submitted date.
- You can filter the list by the submitted by field to see only the jobs submitted by a particular user. You can also sort the list by any of the columns by clicking the column header.
- You can click the job ID to view more details about the job, such as the batches, results, and errors.

.

- You can use the Apex HttpRequest class to make a call out to the API and specify the user ID as a query parameter in the URI. For example, you can use the following URI to get the jobs submitted by a user with the ID 0053h0000036Q7Z:

  /services/data/v53.0/jobs/query?userId=0053h0000036Q7Z
- You can parse the JSON response to get the list of jobs and their details, such as the job ID, status, operation, object, and submitted date.
- You can use the /jobs/query/{jobId} resource for Bulk API 2.0 or the /job/{jobId} resource for Bulk API 1.0 to get more details about a specific job, such as the batches, results, and errors.

Comment: Hey Tushar, I don't think we have list view in the bulk data load jobs setup page. Sorting using columns is one way. /services/data/v53.0/jobs/query?userId also doesn't seem to be using a valid query key. The URI is used to insert and monitor query jobs